# Dynamically add new combo (select) box

Tags: php, javascript, html

In my page, I have a combo box with an add button. How do I create a new combo box below the original combo box when I clicked the add button? If clicked again, it will produce another combo box. The value inside each combo box is called from the database.

Comment: Read about `clone`. I just don't know how to give a full answer.

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo Do u have any link?

Comment: do you have any ideas about jquery? jquery would help you a lot about this problem... please research more and show us what you have already done

Comment: @candy I just create the combo box and a add button. I don't know how create the new combo box dynamically

Comment: @HafizAbdullah Sorry, it was on Stack Overflow several days ago. Search for clone input or element, something like that. It's a common question.

Comment: @Mahan I already searched it but what I found is to add the option value inside the combo box, not a new combo box

Comment: then try to clone the whole existing combobox like this
$('#mycombobox').clone().appendTo('#destination');

Comment: Can you show us your current code so we can base our answers on it.

Comment: please wait im creating a live example for you

Comment: I just noticed you will query DB for values in the combo box. I am thinking  clone may be not enough after all.

Comment: If the values inside of the dynamically created select box need to come from a database, you'll need to use ajax to go back to the server side, query the database, then send the values back to the client.

Comment: maybe he will query first then load it to the combobox, then create a lot of copies of the combox without requerying again the db

Comment: anyways what server-side language you currently using now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example, though you'll have to work out the middle tier and back end portion yourself.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9hvbt/3/

JavaScript

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function(){
    //Use Ajax to talk to your server (middle tier)
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/', //Replace with your URL to return Database data (JSON format)
        dataType: 'json', 
        type: 'get', 
        success: function(data){
            //Use the returned data to pass into CreateDropDown (Hard coded for an example)
            CreateDropDown(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]); 
        }
    });
}); 

function CreateDropDown(data){
    var $newSelect = $('<select />'); 
    $.each(data, function(i, val){
        $newSelect.append($('<option />', {
            'text':val
        }));            
    });  
    $newSelect.appendTo('#dropDowns'); 
}
```

​
    ​
HTML

```
<div id='dropDowns'>
    <select>
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value="Add" />​
```

**EDIT**

You should also read up on [jQuery's AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

any ideas with jquery? jquery clone() will help you to solve this problem

[JQuery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

A LIVE EXAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/6LBNs/

in the case of your problem try to study this one

[Dynamic Loading of ComboBox using jQuery and Ajax](http://www.99points.info/2010/06/ajax-tutorial-dynamic-loading-of-combobox-using-jquery-and-ajax-in-php/)

Comment: The link u gave me loads too long. Can't open it

Comment: please wait im creating a live example for you

Comment: Yeah, but the values in the select box need to be populated from a database, not just an exact clone of the original.

Comment: ahhh... hahah sorry i misunderstood the question... ok then you must use ajax here...